# Fill color in icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-awesome

i am new to css and jquery. I want to fill the color in icon. For example , Like instagram's heart icon (when double tapped it is filled with red color).

I am using font awesome for the same. so i am able to get the heart icon but i can not fill the color the way i want. I tried to change background-color property but it does not work either.

The thing is, when user clicks on the heart icon, it should be filled with the red color. Can you guide me please?

```
My html file
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="all.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="sp"><i class="far fa-heart" id="heart" style="color: green; background-color: red" ></i> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
all.js file is the file i downloaded for icons.
```

What should i use instead of font awesome, if this does not work out?

Comment: switch the image after the click, using a red heart icon.

Comment: Do u want it animated? Cause then you should just search for a "Heart button" on internet and copy paste code. for example: https://codepen.io/bnewton/pen/KrbLkx

Comment: Or just a simple one like https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/MebVWR or https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/gMLeRz

Comment: needed just simple one, thank you so much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a css class to the element to style it's appearance. In my example I added click listener to the element and just toggled CSS clas.

JS code:

```
(function() {
  const heart = document.getElementById('heart');
  heart.addEventListener('click', function() {
    heart.classList.toggle('red');
  });
})();
```

Example Link:

https://codepen.io/bojandevic/pen/mxKZqK

Answer (score 2):

**Why would you reinvent the weel? You don't need to manage this with your own styles.**

In fact **[FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/)** gives you different classes for each icon, for example for the `fa-heart` icon you can use `fa-heart` for a filled heart and `fa-heart-o` for an empty one.

So just use a jQuery code that toggles these two classes on `click` event of your icon:

```
$("#heart").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('fa-heart-o');
  $(this).toggleClass('fa-heart');
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$("#heart").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('fa-heart-o');
  $(this).toggleClass('fa-heart');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<i class="fa fa-heart" id="heart"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery `toggleClass`  you can add or remove classes from each element in the elements like this.

```js
$("#heart").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('oldColor', 'newColor');
});
```

```css
.newColor {
  color: red;
}

.oldColor {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="all.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="sp"><i class="far fa-heart oldColor" id="heart">Heart</i> </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this will not work because the green color is inline style and as you know the inline styles has priority over the classes.

Answer (score 1):

You need add onlick function in the icon, and create a function to change te color of this.

```
<i class="far fa-heart" onclick="changeColor()" id="heart" style="color: green; background-color: red" ></i>
```

And your js should be like:

```
function changeColor()
{
   var icon = document.getElementById('heart');
   icon.style.color = "red";    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use onclick attribute like this:

```
<div id="sp"><i class="far fa-heart" id="heart" onclick="changeColor()" style="color: green;" ></i></div>
```

and in your script area or file define a function like this:

```
function changeColor() {
          document.getElementById("heart").style.color = "red";  }
```